# Appium 1.6 Android. : Location alert

Tags: android, appium, alert

Android Real device with `Appium 1.6` -> I have Location alert at start of my app. However `Appium` is not handling this location alert and gives error that it failed to start the init activity of all.

I have tried following :

```
capabilities.setCapability("locationServicesAuthorized", true);
capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);
capabilities.setCapability("fullReset", true);
```

**Log :**

`Appium]   autoAcceptAlerts: true
[BaseDriver] The following capabilities were provided, but are not recognized by appium: locationServicesAuthorized, autoAcceptAlerts.
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 203a02af-a52f-41ff-b9ec-b71b822bcbff`

[ADB] Found package: 'com.android.packageinstaller' and fully qualified activity name : 'com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity'
[ADB] Incorrect package and activity. Retrying.

[UiAutomator2] UiAutomator2 did not start the activity we were waiting for, '.mobile.ui.main.SplashScreenActivity'. Starting it ourselves

Appium is stuck at com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity activity and its not able to start main init activity.

Can you please help me to get through it .

Also tried following but no use.

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

Thanks,
Sumit

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved by adding following capabilities

```
capabilities.setCapability("appWaitPackage", "com.android.packageinstaller");
capabilities.setCapability("appWaitActivity", ".permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity");
```